# JQuery UI Selectable Box Dimensions / Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

Basically, I'd like to set the `tolerance` to `fit` when I drag the mouse from left to right, and `touch` when I go from right to left (akin to how CAD programs do it). I've looked around and, besides modifying the standard JQuery UI code to move at least 2 variables into a global scope (I'd prefer ***not*** to modify any of the standard files), there doesn't seem to be a method of doing this.

The current method I can see involves modifying the `_mouseDrag` function within `selectable` method, so as to move the `x1` and `x2` variables to a more global state to read them (they represent the start and end points of the selected area box horizontally).

To clarify:

- JQuery = 1.10.2 (Same as in the [JQuery UI demo's](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid))
- JQuery UI = 1.11.4 (Same as in the JQuery UI demo's) (Line 12059 is the start of `_mouseDrag`)
- Browser = Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04, everything up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on `mousemove` if the `clientX` is less or more than `clientX` on the `start` event  and modify the `tolerance` option depending.
Like this:

```
       start: function (e, ui) {
            startX = e.clientX;
            $('#selectable').mousemove(function (e) {
                if (e.clientX < startX) {
                    $('#selectable').selectable('option', 'tolerance', 'touch');
                } else {
                    $('#selectable').selectable('option', 'tolerance', 'fit');
                }
            });
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8fpr6c14/2/